# Add circles with numbers of equal height to pill left of pill text

Tags: html, frontend

I want to add numbered circles left of my text exactly like the image and I want this to be responsive. Can someone please help, it is an emergency! This is what I got until now but it is not quiet like [the image yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Y0J.png).

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

#a1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

#a2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.fs {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id='a1'>1</div>
<div> hi there</div>

<p>or we can do it this way which is better</p>


<div id='container'>

  <div class='fs'>
    <div id='a2' class='fs'>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='fs'> hi there and some more text hi there and some more text hi there and some more text hi there and some more text hi there and some more text hi there and some more text hi there and some more text hi there and some more text</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add some CSS style.

```
#a1, #a2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: It can't be so.
Below I posted answer with code snippet.
Please check again.